# Unity C# Sockets callback that triggers an event logs to console but can't change gameobjects properties

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, asynchronous, thread-safety

I have written the following sockets class to handle the communication between the client and the server, the class simply connects to server and raise an event when a message is received from the server.

```
public class socketsFunctionality : MonoBehaviour
{
    Socket socket;
    public const int BufferSize = 16384; 
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    public delegate void OnAssignCardsDelegate(listOfCards cards);
    public OnAssignCardsDelegate OnAssignCards;

    void Start()
    {
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.2"), 80);

        Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
            new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
    }
    private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {

        socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        socket.EndConnect(ar);
        socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BufferSize, 0,
       new AsyncCallback(CardsReceived), socket);
    }

    private void CardsReceived(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket s = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        int bytesRead = s.EndReceive(ar);
        OnAssignCards.Invoke(new listOfCards());
    }

}
```

And then in another class I subscribe to that event and the event get triggered successfully, and I can write to the console but can't update the ui of the game for some reason.

```
public class tableScript : MonoBehaviour, IDropHandler
{
    void Start()
    {
        socketFunctionality.GetComponent<socketsFunctinality>().OnAssignCards += CardsReceived;
    }

    public void CardsReceived(listOfCards cards)
    {
        Debug.Log("triggered"); //outputs triggered
        gameObject.transform.scale = new Vector3(100f,100f,100f); // nothing happenes
    }
}
```

However, if I move `OnAssignCards.Invoke`to the `Start` function of the `socketsFunctionality` class the code works correctly.

I think it's a threading issue but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Async Receiver, this might be an expected result you are suffering.

I suggested that you should queue all received message with lock, then dequeue and process them in update loop. Or use a while loop in coroutine for checking any new received message. Because invoking events should be called in main thread.

Comment: Or you may send me an email if you need further help. I don’t want to post private solution in public. Email: thelghome@gmail.com

Comment: Sent you an email